# SpringXD module configurations not being picked up

Tags: spring, spring-xd

Using SpringXD mail sink and wanted to configure the mail server settings in a properties file in the module config directory. I created a **mail.properties** file in the **config/modules/sink/mail** directory and placed all my server properties in there. the property names were the same as they are if used inline with the stream definition:

```
host=smtp.example.com
port=25
username=username
password=secret
from=somedude@example.com
```

However these did not get picked up. i know this because when i put them inline into the stream then they worked.

I did check for typos in my file and in my folder/file names and there are none. Is there some special trick to configure modules that come with SpringXD this way?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if you have modules config location set correctly?
By default, it is set to use $XD_HOME/config/modules or you can override this using this enviornment property XD_MODULE_CONFIG_LOCATION

Comment: its configured to use default and i know that is the case because other modules are picking up properties from that config.

Comment: ok, I have just tested it fine. After updating the properties to $XD_HOME/config/modules/sink/mail/mail.properties, I could see the properties are updated with the appropriate values. xd:>module info sink:mail  shows the resolved values as well.

Comment: mine show up there as well, but i still couldn't send an email without getting an "unauthorized" error. It seemed to pick up my host name just fine, but not until i put all the properties into the stream, would it work. Did you actually try sending an email? I will verify again tomorrow to make sure i didn't make a mistake.